"Elephants are one of the endangered animals." — Is "the" obligatory here?
wordreference.com:

(1) Elephants are one of endangered animals. — incorrect
(2) Elephants are one of the endangered animals. — correct

I can't understand why (1) is incorrect.
Do you agree (1) is incorrect?
If you do, then why must we necessarily add "the"?
If not, what's the difference between (1) and (2)?

I don't like either.  "Elephants are endangered animals" is better.

Agreed that (1) is ungrammatical. (2) alludes to something  already in context with "the endangered animals".  E.g. "Some animal species are thriving while others are endangered. Elephants are one of the endangered animals."

Note that, at least in American English, one wouldn’t say, “endangered animal,” but rather, “endangered species.” The former suggests individual, particular creatures—like Wow, look at those elephants over there!

It's worth noting that this question comes from another forum and is quoted from one person's answer. I don't agree with that answer.

(1) Elephants are one of endangered animals.
(2) Elephants are one of the endangered animals.

First of all, one of implies that we are selecting from a specific set, and the set includes other objects in addition to elephants. If we only wanted to say that elephants are endangered animals, we would not use the phrase one of.
Secondly, when we do use one of, we need to describe the specific set. Sentence 1 is wrong because it has no specific larger set. Sentence 2 tries to correct that by adding the. But it still feels incomplete. My first instinct when I read the second sentence was to ask, What endangered animals? To understand this better, compare sentence 2 with other sentences that do describe more clearly a larger set from which elephants are chosen.

(3) Elephants are one of the most endangered animals in Africa.
(4) Elephants are one of the animals on the World Wildlife list of endangered species.
(5) Elephants are one of my favourite animals.

In each of these examples you can easily identify a specific set which is more than elephants alone, and from which elephants have been selected.

+1 for focusing on the need for a specific, determined set in partitive constructions using "one of ________".
